# Android printing and sending of activity to email

Tags: android, email, android-layout, printing

I have an order entry requirement in which the user will enter the order in a tab. After submitting the order, the user can send the order through mail or print via printer. The mail content should be same as they see in the activity. Can anyone suggest me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

E-mail intents is quite simple. You can read a lot more on the subject on [Googles Developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email).

But to summarise with code:

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

You could also add text:

```
Intent.EXTRA_TEXT
```

Or an attachement through a Uri:

```
Intent.EXTRA_STREAM
```